# Cannot fetch href from <a> tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I'm trying to fetch the `href` link from `<a> tag` in `laravel 5.2`- `view(blade)` but it shows `undefined`. i don't exactly understand what's wrong with the code. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the **view** code:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/page/'.$Ids->id)}}" class="clicked-btn" id = 'link'>
  <div class="">
    <img src="{{ asset('img/p1.jpg') }}" class='btn-img'>
  </div>
</a>
```

here's **jQuery**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clicked-btn', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var getLink=this.href;
  console.log(getLink);
}
```

I also tried:

```
$(this).attr('href');
```

**UPDATE**
I think there's some issue with the view. When I inspected elements, i dont know why its turning into:

```
<div class="clicked-btn" id="link">
  <a href="{{URL::to('/page/'.$Ids->id)}}">
    <div class="">
      <img src="{{ asset('img/p1.jpg') }}" class='btn-img'>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` is correct usage. You probably have trobles in your view, not in jquery, attr is not set.

Comment: Both of your approaches will work, although they'll give you different values. `this.href` uses the `href` reflected property, which will be a fully-resolved URL. `$(this).attr("href")` will get you the literal content of the `href` **attribute**, which may be a relative URL, just a hash fragment, etc.

Comment: @DenisMatafonov if you can check the update please

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for the insight, can you please check the update.

Comment: Seems to work... https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/cr7kp6b6/2/

Comment: For semantic reasons, you may not want that div inside the anchor. That may be why your inspector is altering the markup.

Comment: @Scott: It shouldn't be (and isn't in your fiddle, with Chrome), putting a `div` inside an anchor is just fine. The content model of `a` is [*transparent*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) (with *no [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) allowed*).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree it *shouldn't be*.... but when troubleshooting.. lowest common denominator and all that. :)

Comment: At least the reworked DOM explains the `this.href` thing; `this` in the handler is the `div` once it's been reworked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know, how conventional this code is, but seeing the inspect elements code, I tried hard to prevent the changes in the html structure. Failed, I finally used this:

```
$(this).children("a").attr('href');
```

I'm still open to better solutions if any one has-do share. This is just a contribution for helping people who face the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

This Javascript will work with first html code before update...

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clicked-btn', function () {
var el = $(this);
console.log(el.attr('href'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.ex.com" class="clicked-btn" id = 'link'>
  <div class="">
    some code
  </div>
</a>
```